# how to swap scroll with right click in a specific application?

Tags: google-chrome, mouse, scroll-wheel

my mouse's scroll is not working well.when I push it down, It sometimes not works, sometimes works twice.
What I want is a tool, to swap middle mouse button(pushing scroll down) with right click button in a specific application(in this case chrome). I'm sure I middle click links to open in new tab much more than times I right click.
any help on it would be very good.

Comment: wouldnt a new mouse be a better solution?

Comment: @Keltari I don't use middle mouse click anywhere else. only where I use it is in chrome for opening new tab. and scroll is working.problem is just middle "click".